Displaying text in OpenGL (2024 update wanted)
I am trying hard to get text to display in OpenGL in any way, shape, or form. To start from something very simple, I grabbed this example from GeeksForGeeks. It runs, it displays a green circle. Then I went researching around and found several text drawing examples including the first answer here. The simple ones seem to converge on one strategy, which I implemented on lines 40-42. Unfortunately, no letter A appears.
Looking at the gluOrtho2D projection, it certainly seems that (0, 0) ought to be in the middle of the window, and quite visible.  True?
I can find several questions and answers on this topic, but like the one I referenced, they are all OLD. More than 10 years old. Has something critical changed that invalidates this approach? If so, an update would be much appreciated.  Or any other strategy on how to get the letter A to appear.
// C program to demonstrate 
// drawing a circle using 
// OpenGL 
#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION

#include<stdio.h> 
#include<math.h> 
#include<GLUT/glut.h> 
#define pi 3.142857 
  
// function to initialize 
void myInit (void) { 
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    glPointSize(1.0); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  
    glLoadIdentity(); 
      
    gluOrtho2D(-780, 780, -420, 420); 
} 
  
void display (void)  { 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glBegin(GL_POINTS); 
    float x, y, i; 
      
    // iterate y up to 2*pi, i.e., 360 degree 
    // with small increment in angle as 
    // glVertex2i just draws a point on specified co-ordinate 
    for ( i = 0; i < (2 * pi); i += 0.001) 
    { 
        // let 200 is radius of circle and as, 
        // circle is defined as x=r*cos(i) and y=r*sin(i) 
        x = 200 * cos(i); 
        y = 200 * sin(i); 
        glVertex2i(x, y); 
    } 
    glEnd(); 
    // NOT WORKING:
    glColor3f (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRasterPos2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13, 'A');
    glFlush(); 
} 

int main (int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    glutInit(&argc, argv); 
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); 
    glutInitWindowSize(1366, 768); 
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0); 
      
    glutCreateWindow("Circle Drawing"); 
    myInit(); 
    glutDisplayFunc(display); 
    glutMainLoop(); 
} 


"they are all OLD. More than 10 years old" - The use of glutBitmapCharacter is even more outdated than 10 years. I recommend reading LearnOpenGL - Text Rendering

btw, the above example works on Ubuntu and displays red A character in the middle of green circle (taking into account correct include headers there and compilation flags)

@yvs2014, that's fascinating! I'm running on macOS 14.2.1using the llvm  toolchain, and seeing no letter. Any insights?

Thanks, @Rabbid76. I have followed your link and that strikes me as a frustratingly large amount of work for a level of quality and control that I don't need. My short term need is to display debugging information on the screen in a relevant location, i.e. close to the relevant feature in my 3D image. Is FreeType really going to be the shortest path to that goal, these days?

@Rabbid76 Further thoughts: What I'm really seeing in that textbook is a low-level  approach. Is there a higher-level library out there that would do most of that for me?  Font caching, rendering sizes as needed, etc.?
The code I got from GeeksForGeeks is not shader-aware. Working with legacy code as I am, I'd rather stay that way if possible. Is it possible?
